# Sql Query to transfer all records on another column on THE SAME table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**Original Table Setup:**

```
 Table Name: property_details
 Attribute: property_id, floor_area
```

Now, a new attribute is added named: total_area.

There are already records on **property_details** table with corresponding id and wanted to copy floor_area data to **total_area**. (Will do something floor_area later)

For clarification, if this is in excel I will copy the value of A1 to B2 on the same row. Pretty simple to demonstrate but can't figured out using sql.

**Is this possible working on the same table?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run an `UPDATE` statement wherein the value of `floor_area` is copied to `total_area`, example,

```
UPDATE property_details
SET total_area= floor_area
```

Comment: Yes I have this answer in my mind but my concern is about the ids'. Does this cause any issue with the Ids? Actually, I can't do the trial and error here since there are lots of data already. thanks

Comment: don'to worry about the `ID`. the statement is run on every row, so the affected value of the column is from the row itself.

Answer (score 0):

better option can be to rather change the name of the feilds from 
total_area to floor_area
takes very less execution time and efficient in this case 
but however ypur problem of ids may occur better first try to sample or in a small set of tables